# Group by with a foreign key on single LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have 2 related tables and they are

**Schedule**

```
SlotId
Description 
Amount
```

and **Slot**

```
Id
Name
```

Example data:

**Schedule**

```
slotid    description    amount
--------------------------------
    1     Morning charge   300
    1     Late fee         300
    1     Earlier bonus    200
    1     Half day         150
    2     Morning charge   300
    2     Late fee         300
    2     Earlier bonus    200
    2     Half day         150
    3     Morning charge   300
    3     Late fee         300
    3     Earlier bonus    200
    3     Half day         150
```

Final result wanted as a `SlotSchedules` list, like this:

```
    SlotId
    SlotName
    List<Schedules>
```

I need:

- fetched list of Schedules
- and then find distinct slots in it
- and then iterate through each slot and build the model i needed  as below

This is what I tried with LINQ:

```
    List<Schedules>  schedulesAll = (from n in dbContext.Schedules                                
                                    select n).ToList();

    var slotsdistinct = schedulesAll.Select(x => x.SlotId).Distinct().ToList();

    foreach (var slot in slotsdistinct)
    {
        var scheduledforslot = schedulesAll.Where(x => x.SlotId == slot).Select(x => x).ToList();  

        foreach (Schedules _schedule in scheduledforslot)
        {
            //ListModel.Add(new DetailsModel { Name = _schedule.Description, Amount = (_schedule.Amount });
        }
    }
```

Any way to make it in single LINQ query?

Comment: Show us what you tried in C# then we will fix it with you :)

Comment: @CodeNotFound Please see the edit

Comment: You are using only the `Schedule` table in your code, is it enough? didn't you want to join the tables?

Comment: they are related via foreign key slotid

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  var slotsSchedules = dbContext.Slots.ToList().Select(slot => new { 
                       SlotID = slot.Id, 
                       Name = slot.Name,
                       SlotSchedules = dbContext.Schedules.ToList()
                                      .Where(schedule = > schedule.SlotId == slot.Id).ToList()});
```